# Chaining conditions using meteors' currentUser helper

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using the currentUser helper in m template file and i was wondering whether how i can achieve this.

`<h5 class="panel-title"> {{#if currentUser.profile.userrole = 'schooladmin' or 'teacher' or 'student' or 'parent' or 'superadmin'}} Academic Years {{/if}}</h5>`

I want to chain using if using the or statement.

The above chaining causes this error

```
Can't have a non-keyword argument
   after a keyword argument
```

How can i correct this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing all this in Blaze, just make a helper and call that in your view.

```
Template.xxx.helpers({
     customLogic: function() {
          return (Meteor.user().profile.userrole === 'schooladmin' || other logics);
     }
});


{{#if customLogic}}
     Academic Years
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Can i use this globally like define the helper once and use it this `{{#if customLogic}}
     Academic Years
{{/if}}` in any template i choose?.

Comment: yes this is generally possible. If the helper depends on the data context then that may create some restrictions in where you can use the global helper.

Answer (score 0):

I have dined a global helper

```
Template.registerHelper("custom", function() {
       return (Meteor.user().profile.userrole === 'schooladmin' || 'teacher' ||  'student' || 'parent' || 'superadmin');
});
```

and used it like so

`<h5 class="panel-title"> {{#if custom}} Academic Years{{/if}}</h5>`